# pandas slice 3-level multiindex based on a list with 2 levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, multi-index

Here is a minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [6, 7]])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(18), index=idx)
selection = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

I would like to select all the rows in `df` that have as index that starts with any of the items in `selection`. So I would like to get the sub dataframe of `df` with the indices:

```
(1, 'a', 6), (1, 'a', 7), (2, 'b', 6), (2, 'b', 7)
```

What is the most straightforward/pythonian/pandasian way of doing this? What I found:

```
sel = [id[:2] in selection for id in df.index]
df.loc[sel]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
out = df[df.index.isin(selection)]
```

Output:

```
              0
1 a 6  1.560268
    7  0.674709
2 b 6  0.848069
    7  0.130719
```

If you want to select other levels, drop the unused leading levels:

```
# here we want to select on levels 1 and 2
selection = [('a', 6), ('b', 7)]

df[df.index.droplevel(0).isin(selection)]
```

Output:

```
              0
1 a 6  1.560268
  b 7  0.137769
2 a 6  0.754946
  b 7  0.130719
3 a 6 -2.275646
  b 7 -2.199944
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really cool! Wondering how come one doesn't need to write the .loc here: df.loc[df.index.isin(selection)]

Comment: @Chachni you could, but since it's boolean indexing this also works by default on rows with `df[boolean_array]`

Comment: This definitely feels like the most elegant, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
print(pd.concat([df.loc[(*t, slice(None)), :] for t in selection]))
```

Prints:

```
              0
1 a 6  0.701403
    7 -0.822042
2 b 6 -0.610558
    7 -0.433880
```

Comment: It also gives (1, b) and (2,a) for some reason...

Answer (score 2):

One option is with pyjanitor's [select](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select) function:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
df.select(rows=selection)
              0
1 a 6 -0.989212
    7 -1.951114
2 b 6  1.629402
    7  0.298262
```

This works because the first two rows of the tuples coincide with the first two levels of the index. @mozways' solution is more generic

Comment: Always a nice alternative ;)

Comment: I didn't fully understand the limitation you expressed @sammywemmy. Could you please explain what wouldn't work?

Comment: if the  levels of the tuples are not in the same order as the dataframe's index, then it wont work - say the index has three levels, and we select on levels 0 and 1, then yes it works fine. if however the levels were 1 and 2, as used in @mozway's second example, then it will fail. the `isin` approach however, used by @mozway covers this.